# Signal app - can senders see when the recipient has read the message?

Tags: applications, encryption, privacy

With the [Signal app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/signal-private-messenger/id874139669), can senders see when the recipient has read the message? I notice those two hatches but don't they just mean the message has been sent?